# Condition on lookup Talend

Tags: database, oracle11g, talend

I would like to implement a condition in talend with a tMap. I dont know how to select a field who depend of a value in a lookup.

here is my job :

[image]

In my Tmap i would like to do something like that :

if M02_MOYENDIFFUSION **is equal to M21_LIBELLECOURT OR M21_LIBELLELONG** then i take the M21_ID.

[image]

But currently, talend take M21_ID only if M02_MOYENDIFFUSION  is equal to M21_LIBELLECOURT **AND** M21_LIBELLELONG

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the filtering box of the input in Tmap, It will filter your data using the filter expression.

[image]

For more, see [Talend help](https://www.talendforge.org/tutorials/tutorial.php?language=english&idTuto=9&nbrFields=10).